# Loop over dataframes and plot means and CIs

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, functional-programming, dplyr

I have 7 dataframes showing mean and confidence intervals of a column across quartiles of different variables which I produced using the function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Rmisc) 

means.data <- function(data, x, y) {
  summarySE(data, measurevar=y,groupvars=x,  na.rm = TRUE)
}
bmd.tblmq <- means.data(data, 'tblm.q', 'thip_bmd')
bmd.sarc3 <- means.data(data, 'sarc_status_3cat', 'thip_bmd')
bmd.sppbb <- means.data(data, 'sppb_cats', 'thip_bmd')
bmd.grpsq <- means.data(data, 'grip_strength.q', 'thip_bmd')
bmd.gaitq <- means.data(data, 'gait_speed.q', 'thip_bmd')
bmd.frcq <- means.data(data, 'force.q', 'thip_bmd')
bmd.powrq <- means.data(data, 'power.q', 'thip_bmd')

str(bmd.tblmq)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  6 variables:
$ tblm.q  : Factor w/ 4 levels "(27.9,34.5]",..: 1 2 3 4 NA
$ N       : num  68 82 74 62 1
$ thip_bmd: num  0.813 0.836 0.912 0.924 0.632
$ sd      : num  0.118 0.136 0.145 0.125 NA
$ se      : num  0.0143 0.015 0.0169 0.0159 NA
$ ci      : num  0.0285 0.0299 0.0336 0.0317 NA
```

I would like to use a function/loop to plot the mean and CI for each dataframe without having to repeat the code below for each dataframe and each x variable:

```
bmd.tblm.plot <- ggplot(data=subset(bmd.tblmq, !is.na(tblm.q)), 
                        aes(x=tblm.q, y=thip_bmd, ymin=thip_bmd-ci, ymax=thip_bmd+ci)) +
  geom_pointrange()  + 
  xlab("Lean mass quartile") + ylab("Mean TH BMD (95% CI)") +
  ggtitle("TH BMD: lean mass quartile") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Q1", "Q2","Q3", "Q4"))
```

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data, not the structure of it. There is likely a way to do this with a function from either the `apply` or `purrr::map` families

Comment: column names of all 7 dataframes seem to be different ? Do you really want to use a loop for this? @aelhak

Comment: @YOLO - could a loop be used by column index i.e. they might have different names but the xvar is always column #1?

Comment: @aelhak I tried but turns out the column you are using to make plots don't occur at same indexes. For example, in bld.tblmq, index 1 is column N. Does all other data frame follows the exact structure ? Then, using index is a possible thing, but then you still need to change the plot title for each title. Right ?